# ZooKeeper TIme Synchronization

Tags: time, apache-zookeeper

How does ZooKeeper deal with time ?
Are the Znodes/Clients synchronized ? and How?
Otherwise, how does the algorithm work without time Synchronization?

I see relative Question here, but it does not answer my question
[How does Zookeeper synchronize the clock in the cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554377/how-does-zookeeper-synchronize-the-clock-in-the-cluster)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As you may have heard, zookeeper elects a leader for the ensemble. Thereafter, all the write requests go through the leader.

Therefore, leader is responsible for preserving the order of write requests. (Yes, the order is determined by the time at which a request reaches the leader). When all the write requests are served by the leader, no need to worry about synchronization right? Zookeeper doesn't depend on synchronizations of clocks.

How the leader is transmitting new values to the followers is another problem which is addressed through **consensus** algorithm, ZAB (Zookeeper Atomic Broadcast). This protocol make sure that the majority of the ensemble have updated the new value before sending **OK** response to the write request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
What is the rule of NTP in Zookeeper then? Is it to keep synchronization between the user and all elected leaders over a period of time?